# How to take exactly one character input and show output as soon as character is typed?

Tags: java, character

The thing is to take **exactly** one character as input and output should be presented **without hitting** return as soon as a character is typed onto the console.

```
char a;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
a = s.next().charAt(0);
```

I tried this but it still asked for the return key for output.

Comment: There's no real way to do this in Java as much of the input is taken from the systems input stream which is "kind of" buffered (until the user presses enter).  Depending on your needs, you could look at some of the cursors APIs, but this involves a level of native integration...

Comment: look at the KeyListener class, it allows you to get keyboard events

Comment: @CharlieS Which only works in AWT or Swing GUI environments...

Comment: 3 words: [Native Key Listener](http://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/). No need for `Scanner`, although the user won't see his input (you could always print it to console manually, though)

Answer (score 0):

If your program must be console based, you have to switch your terminal out of line mode into character mode, and remember to restore it before your program quits. There is no portable way to do this across operating systems.

Here is [an article on 
Non-blocking console input](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/non-blocking-console-io-is-not-possible/)  that will provide more details